# Вычисление определителя и передача массива в метод Java

Tags: java, массивы

Задался целью написать алгоритм для вычисления определителя матрицы размером 3*3.

Попробовал такой код:

**Opredelitel.java**

```
public class Opredelitel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Minor Min = new Minor();
        Double[] Crew = new Double[13];
        Double[][] MatrixNet = new Double[3][3];
        MatrixNet[0][0] = 0.1;
        MatrixNet[0][1] = 0.5;
        MatrixNet[0][2] = 1.5;

        MatrixNet[1][0] = 1.1;
        MatrixNet[1][1] = 1.5;
        MatrixNet[1][2] = 1.0;

        MatrixNet[2][0] = 2.1;
        MatrixNet[2][1] = 2.5;
        MatrixNet[2][2] = 0.5;

        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < MatrixNet.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < MatrixNet.length; j++)
                    if ((i != k) & (j != 0)) {
                        int t = 0;
                        Crew[t] = MatrixNet[i][j];

                        double m = Min.Chek(MatrixNet[0][0], MatrixNet[1]
                                [0], MatrixNet[2][0], Crew);
                        System.out.print(m);
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Minor.java**

```
public class Minor {
    public double m;
    public double Chek(double MatrixNet1, double MatrixNet2, double MatrixNet3,
                       Double[] Crew) {
        for (int i=0; i<=13;i++)
            m = double MatrixNet1*(Crew [0]*Crew [3]-Crew [1]*Crew [2])-double
        MatrixNet2*(Crew [4]*Crew [7]+Crew [5]*Crew [6])-double MatrixNet3*(Crew
                [8]*Crew [11]-Crew [9]*Crew [10]);
        return m;
    }
}
```

В вызывающем методе 3-мя циклами отбираются элементы трех алгебраических дополнений, для элементов в 3-х строках. То есть всего 12 элементов. С этой задачей алгоритм справляется превосходно.

На следующем этапе я хотел эти 12 элементов `MatrixNet[i][j]` записать в новый, уже одномерный массив `Crew[t]`, затем передать этот новый массив в качестве аргумента в метод Minor, в котором уже вычисляется определитель, как сумма произведений соответствующих элементов на их алгебраические дополнения. Соответствующие элементы передаю также в качестве аргументов.

В результате выдает: `NullPointedException`

Попробовал упростить задачу. Передавал только массив (без отдельных элементов) и в методе `Minor` вычислял. К примеру: `Crew [0] + Crew [2]`.

Выдает то же самое.

Comment: Укажите полное исключение со стектрейсом и в какой строке оно возникает.

Comment: класс Minor содержит ошибки и не будет компилироваться совсем. если вы хотите преобразовать тип, то нужно использовать скобки.

Comment: что такое `Crew`, почему в нем 13 элементов, и почему значение присваивается только нулевому?

Comment: `if ((i != k) & (j != 0)) {` - `&&`?

Comment: Crew - это одномерный массив элементов, в который записывается 12  элементов алгебраических дополнений. Я посчитал, что в одномерном массиве будет легче передать эти 12 элементов в метод Minor.

Comment: исключение возникает в double m = Min.Chek(MatrixNet[0][0], MatrixNet[1][0], MatrixNet[2][0], Crew);

Comment: и также возникает в m = double MatrixNet1*(Crew [0]*Crew [3]-Crew [1]*Crew [2])-double MatrixNet2*(Crew [4]*Crew [7]+Crew [5]*Crew [6])-double MatrixNet3*(Crew [8]*Crew [11]-Crew [9]*Crew [10]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Double** - это полноценный объект и если вы описываете массив **Double**, то по умолчанию всем ячейкам этого массива будет присвоено значение **null**. И при попытке **unboxing** этого значения и будет сгенерировано исключение **NPE**.

У вас есть 2 простых выхода:

1. Замените все **Double** на **double**
2. Проинициализируйте каждую ячейку массива `Crew`

   ```
   Arrays.fill(Crew, 0.0);
   ```

Первый вариант предпочтительней, так как в вашей задаче нет смысла использовать **обертки**.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я изначально использовал double, а Идея мне почему-то предлагает изменить на Double...   Если оставляю double пишет (указывая на строку double m = Min.Chek(MatrixNet[0][0], MatrixNet[1][0], MatrixNet[2][0], Crew);) следующее: Incompatible types: java.lang.Double [] cannot be converted to double [].   То есть, она воспринимает Crew, который я хочу передать в качестве аргумента, как обертку?

Comment: Да, ну я дебил, я же  в объявлении массивов Crew и MatrixNet указал Double...  Поправил.   Теперь запускается без ошибки. НО выдает не тот результат, что я ожидал. Выводит 12 элементов, а должен выводиться один результат m. Результат вычисления в методе Minor

Comment: вы получили ответ на ваш вопрос? NPE больше не возникает? тогда либо принимайте ответ, либо удалите вопрос и создайте новый.

Comment: Ответ принимаю. Чуть позднее задам другой вопрос по тому же коду